# Is the inability for people to accept they may be wrong on a topic (and the rationales for that) something that psychology ever discusses in depth?

Tags: personality, motivation, behavior

Pride, shame, hubris and ego being factors in whether a person is able to consider they may be wrong on a statement, claim or stance on a topic.  Not only consider wrongness, but accept or note their change of mind.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  This is one of the more common questions on this forum.  Other examples include: [Denial of evidence and reason](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/13173/7001), [Do people have a tendency to stick to one opinion after they formed it?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/117/7001), [Which is the scientific name of stubbornness?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/5878/7001)

Comment: Thanks for that. I was working on something in this space (total amateur here), and thought I was doing quite well mapping out all the concepts, but now realize I'd only mapped the tip of the iceberg.

Answer (score 1):

This was discussed by [Erich Fromm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_Fromm), a German social psychologist. In his popular book "To Have or to Be?" he explains this mode of attached to one's own conviction as the modes of existence related to "Having" as if this was one's property that it is about to defend. On the other hand, people living in the mode of "Being" do not "posess" their ideas but are open to learn new things, the best what can happen in a conversation.